# How would I attempt this in R:

Tags: r, for-loop

Please assist me, im a noob :)

Using a for-loop, find the value of the following expression: 1 + 2/ 3 + (2 /3 × 4/ 5 ) + (2/ 3 × 4/ 5 × 6/ 7 ) + ⋯ + ( 2 /3 × 4 /5 … 38 /39)

Answer (score 0):

```
n<-10

x<-0
y<-numeric(n)

for(i in 1:n)
{
y[i]<-((2*i)/((2*i)+1))
x<-x+prod(y)
}
x<-1+x
```

Comment: With n=10 this only goes up to the 20/21 term.

Comment: you can change n to 19

Answer (score 0):

- You can use `sapply` along with `sum`+ `prod`, i.e.,

```
s <- sum(sapply(0:19, 
                function(k) ifelse(k==0,
                                   1,
                                   prod(2*seq(k)/(2*seq(k)+1)))))
```

such that

```
> s
[1] 6.976346
```

- Here is the `for` loop version

```
s <- 0
for (k in 0:19) {
  if (k==0) {
    s <- s + 1
  } else {
    s <- s + prod(2*seq(k)/(2*seq(k)+1))
  }
}
> s
[1] 6.976346
```

Comment: thank you. however it is required to use a for-loop but this is an interesting approach.

Comment: or is this seen as a for - loop?

Comment: @HerbertPeters see my updates. `sapply` is kind of loop

Comment: thank you so much. actually quite simple. as i said, i am new to this.